# Passing appsecret_proof param in fb graph api request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the [fb graph sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk). The require secret key is disabled in my fb app setting. The docs [says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/)

> If you're using the official PHP SDK, the appsecret_proof parameter is automatically added.

So I am not passing the `appsecret_proof` in my request. I am using is as -

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
          'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
          'enable_beta_mode' => false,
          'default_access_token' => 'xxxxxx',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.X',
          'http_client_handler' => 'curl',
          'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory'
        ]);
$fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,gender');

This throws an error-
    Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument
```

How can I include the `appsecret_proof` in my above request.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and feel really stupid about this. 
For testing purpose I had generated an access_token from the facebook graph explorer. While logging in via postman I was using the app details for an app for which the fb id and secret was not present in my local db. I updated these details and things worked fine.
So the official PHP SDK does sends out the appsecret_proof parameter is automatically.